# Splitting k - combinations into 2 in a specific manner in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Consider a set,

```
 S = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

I am trying to come up with a function which takes S as the input and gives me ALL possible arrays:

```
 [ 1 ~ 2 ; 1 ~ 3 ; 1 ~ 4 ; 1 ~ 5 ; . . . ; 6 ~ 7 ]
 [ 1 2 ~ 3 ; 1 2 ~ 4 ; ...; 2 3 ~ 1 ; 2 3 ~ 4....; 5 6 ~ 7]
 .
 .
 .
 [ 2 3 4 5 6 7 ~ 1 ; 1 3 4 5 6 7 ~ 2 ; ... ; 1 2 3 4 5 6 ~ 7 ]
```

Here notice that '~' is sort of like a delimiter placed in between the elements of k - combination such that the set appearing before the delimiter is always unique in each array.

For example, we want both 7-combinations

```
 [ 2 3 4 5 6 7 ~ 1 ] and [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ~ 7 ].
```

But we want only one of

```
 [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ~ 7 ] and [ 1 3 4 5 6 2 ~ 7 ].
```

My Code :

```
clear all
for k = 1:7
    Set = nchoosek(1:7,k); 
        for i = 1:length(Set)
            A = setdiff(1:7,Set(i,:));
            P = nchoosek( A , 2 ); % trialing it for only A~B where B has only 2elements
            L = length( P );
            S = repmat( Set ( i,: ) , L,1);
            for  j = 1:L

                S1(j,:) = setdiff( S(j,:) , P(j,:) );
                W(j,:) = [ S1(j,:) , 0 , P(j,:) ];

            end

             W1(i,k) = {W};

        end

end
```

This however produces an error at k=2. 
Any ideas to make this work and efficiently.

Comment: Also, possible to generalize this for all possible s(1<s<7) where s is the no. of elements appearing after the delimiter?

Comment: your question is a bit confusing. First you ask for *all* - but then you want only "the set before the delimiter" to be unique. Finally you give an example where the number *after* the delimiter is unique.

Comment: I'm sorry if its confusing. See if this is clearer. I want all the possible arrays which stipulate to the condition I had explained with the example. 

The number after delimiter is unique automatically if you have the set appearing before the delimiter to be unique.

Comment: so what is the rule why you want only one of [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ~ 7 ] and [ 1 3 4 5 6 2 ~ 7 ]?

Comment: I don't want 2 (or more) vectors where the set before the delimiter is the same. So, take A~B. For a certain B, I only want one permutation of A and not more.

Comment: so any of the permutations of A would be ok?

Comment: I have added my code. Check it out.

Comment: you have an error in there `S1` definitely needs to be declared before the loop. From what I understand also one of the `nchoosek` is superfluous. Anyway can't say I follow your thought - can you put down  how your algorithm is supposed to work.

Comment: It doesn't matter actually where S1 is defined. Probably better to define it outside for efficiency but really doesn't do anything to cause an error.

Comment: Firstly, the second nchoosek is not exactly superfluous because it gives you combinations of elements not in `Set(i,:)`. 

I'd request you to run the code, to hopefully clear up things,  with a break point at `W1`. And you can see for `k=1` , `W1` gives the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can outline how to achieve this.

- to get the subset (for A) use `setdiff`

  `s = 1:7
  b = 4
  tmp = setdiff(s,b)`
- for the permutation use `randperm`

  `t2 = randperm(length(tmp))
  A = tmp(t2)`
- for the specific subsets just pick the first n entries of A

Put the whole thing in some loops to create the set you describe.

Comment: What would make this simpler that to get all permitted permutations with `nchoosek`?

Comment: I was curious about this as well - but it seems the question was *not* about getting *all* permutations, but a relative small subset. Anyway I'm just suggesting some details are still not clear to me.